# Suppressing error messages in PowerShell ErrorVariable

Tags: powershell

Using the snippet below, I'm trying to find a way to suppress the "Attempted to divide by zero" error, and be left with just the custom error message in $err. I've tried combinations of try/catch, Invoke-Command/Expression, redirecting 2>$null, but in every case the error stream still contains the "attempted to divide by zero" message.

```
function func1 {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()

  func2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable er
  if ($er.Count -ge 1) {
    Write-Error -Message "Custom error message!"
  }
}

function func2 {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()

  1/0
}

func1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err
$err
```

populates $err with two items:

```
Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:15 char:3
+   1/0
+   ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
 
func1 : Custom error message!
At line:18 char:1
+ func1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,func1
```

Thanks so much for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the solution is somewhat tricky, because the error that occurs in `func2` is *invariably* recorded in the `$err` variable passed to `-ErrorVariable` in the `func1` invocation, and is already stored there when the `func2` call returns.

Therefore you need to *manually remove it*:

Replace:

```bash
if ($er.Count -ge 1) {
  Write-Error -Message "Custom error message!"
}
```

with:

```bash
if ($er.Count -ge 1) {
  if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ErrorVariable')) {
    # Remove the most recently added error from the $err variable.
    $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue($PSBoundParameters['ErrorVariable']).RemoveAt(0)
  }
  Write-Error -Message "Custom error message!"
}
```

- The [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) allows you to check if the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) was specified and with what value (i.e., what target variable name).
- The [automatic `$PSCmdlet` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscmdlet)'s `.GetVariableValue()` method allows access to variables defined in the *caller's* scope, which enables retrieving the target variable value, which is a [`[System.Collections.ArrayList]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) instance whose `.RemoveAt()` method can be called to remove the most recently added error, which is at index `0`.

Asides:

- `1/0` causes a *statement-terminating* error, whereas the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) only acts on *non-terminating* errors (to catch *terminating* errors you need [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally)). However, because this statement-terminating error occurs *inside a function*, execution inside that function (potentially) continues, and *to the caller* the error is in effect a *non-terminating* one.
- For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's bewilderingly complex error handling, see [GitHub docs issue #1583](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

Comment: Thanks! That's useful... but I don't believe addresses the original problem. If I encapsulate the call to func1 in a try/catch block, it does not help me to suppress the "Attempted to divide my zero" error contained in $err.

Comment: In your catch block use ``throw “<your custom message here”`` to perform a terminating error and stop the script or use ``write-error “your message”``

Comment: @Fitzgery, it turns out that no `try` / `catch` was ultimately needed, and the real goal (which I initially missed) was to prevent the `1/0` error from surfacing in the `$err` variable passed to the outer function call's `-ErrorVariable` parameter. Doing so requires tricky manual manipulation of this variable, unfortunately.